# How to undo "set -x" in unix shell?

Tags: shell, unix

In following some random directions on the internet, trying to debug an issue of mine at a shell (I use zsh), I ran `set -x`. Thanks to this I figured out my issue. However, I'm now in an awkward position of not knowing how to turn this debugging off -- I really don't even understand what I did in the first place, you see.

I also figured out that I could just do `zsh` and get a new shell. The obvious `unset -x` does not work. I would like to know the correct way. Thanks!

**Update:**

Found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124272/what-do-the-arguments-v-and-x-mean-to-bash) unix&linux stack exchange post about what `-x` does. Still don't know how to turn it off.

Comment: How to undo it to its previous state? It can have been `+x` or `-x` before.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `set +x` to switch it back. The output of `help set` describes this:

```
$ help set
set: set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option] [arg ...]
    ...
    -v  Print shell input lines as they are read.
    -x  Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.
    ...

Using + rather than - causes these flags to be turned off.  The
flags can also be used upon invocation of the shell.  The current
set of flags may be found in $-.  The remaining n ARGs are positional
parameters and are assigned, in order, to $1, $2, .. $n.  If no
ARGs are given, all shell variables are printed.
```

Note the “Using `+` rather than `-` causes these flags to be turned off” part.